# How to read a JSON object with a full-stop in the name using POSTMAN?

Tags: json, testing, postman, postman-testcase

I have a problem trying to check a JSON value in the response body using POSTMAN because the JSON object name has a full-stop in it

Usually a JSON response body would be something like this:

```
{
"restapi": "Beta",
"logLevel": "INFO"
}
```

So normally we can do a test on the JSON value like this using POSTMAN:

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.restapi).to.eql(Beta);
});
```

But the problem I'm having now is that the JSON object name has a full stop like this

```
{
    "restapi.name": "Beta",
    "logLevel.sleep": "INFO"
}
```

So if I try to do read the object like this, it will come out with an error

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.restapi.name).to.eql(Beta);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reference the `key` value by using `brackets` around the name:

`jsonData["restapi.name"]`

Answer (score 0):

object properties can be accessed with `.` operator or with associative array indexing using `[]`. ie. `object.property` is equivalent to `object["property"]`

this should do the trick

```
jsonData["restapi.name"]
```